# speeding up google charts rendering or alternatives

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-visualization

So I need to display basic graphs for around 30,000 data points and I am currently using Google Charts with the following code in javascript with a little jinja thrown in there:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('number', 'Time');
          data.addColumn('number', "value1");
          data.addColumn('number', "value2");
          var mnemonic_count = 1;
          {% for item in response %}
            data.addRow([mnemonic_count, {{item["value1"] | safe}}, {{item["value2"] | safe}}]);
            count = count+1;
          {% endfor %}

          console.log(count);

          var options = {
            chart: {
              title: 'value over time',
              subtitle: 'count . ' data points'
            },
            width: 900,
            height: 500
          };

          var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>

<html>
    <div id="linechart_material"></div>
</html>
```

This works just fine with small data sets and it never really fails but when I get up the number of data points I need, circa 30,000 it takes almost 30 seconds to load. Is there anything I can do on the backend to speed this up or does anyone know if a browser based chart that can render faster?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, some charting libs just aren't built to handle big data sets. If your own optimizations don't pan out, switching to another library might be the best solution.

Some more heavyweight options include [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com), [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com), and - if you're ready for a steep learning curve - [d3.js](http://d3js.org).

I'm on the ZingChart team, and we built a [render speed demo](http://www.zingchart.com/demos/zingchart-vs/) using some common libraries. It might help you get a feel for normal render times with different data sets. Bear in mind that interactive features and the number / type of chart elements (aside from data points) will affect speeds as well. Note that some combinations of library/render tests may kill the page or lock up your browser for a bit. We allowed this in order to demonstrate true behavior.

If you have any questions about the subject or ZingChart, feel free to reach out to us.

Comment: Any chance you could point me to information on why this service is so much faster when it seems like it is also a heavier feature set?

Comment: You're very welcome! It's all in the implementation of the underlying library and how sensitive to the data you are providing. For example, lets take this example I pulled from the google charts docs on how to create a line chart.  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart http://plnkr.co/edit/wqH4SM68dcLXzr6jnfzm?p=preview Now if you inspect the dom, you will see that it stores a copy of its data is stored in <tables>! This will eventually lead to a dom explosion especially if you need 30,000 points.

Comment: The key to fast performance is memory management and making sure the end result is not over utilizing the fragile DOM. Another big factor for speed is how the library treats the visualization of the data provided. Again, I will be focusing on google charts. http://plnkr.co/edit/50kKUUg8xtl9m4PcX6BW?p=preview

Comment: In this example, the dataset consists of a linear progression. If you inspect the dom carefully and find the svg path used to draw the blue line, you will see an excessive amount of path coordinates just to draw a straight line; a large waste of resources. This means that the implementation calculates a data point's position regardless to the screen resolution. While this approach is for accuracy, an algorithm could be applied to not only make it accurate but could save performance by estimating the visualization for the appropriate screen resolution; enough for the human eye.

Comment: We've spent countless hours making sure our customers can render charts of 100k+ points in an efficient amount of time without losing any accuracy. :)

Comment: Your benchmark demo link does not work anymore unfortunately @RockinSocks

Comment: @guruz, thanks for the heads up! I'm no longer on the ZC team, but I've reached out to a couple devs that still are - they should be able to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

You may get a faster response by using [arrayToDataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#arraytodatatable)(), giving it a single array that you construct by just pushing rows onto it, rather than adding one row at a time with 30000 datatable.addRow() calls.

Comment: Hmm good idea! But it only sped it up by around 10% so from 30s to 27s